# Get element in Array

Tags: arrays, revit-api

In the execution of my code, how do I get the `r.diameter` element, which is stored in an `array`, to another code function?

```
public static RebarProps [] GetRebarsHor (Element el, Document doc)
    {
        
        var rebars = RebarHostData.GetRebarHostData(el).GetRebarsInHost();
        var rlst = new List<RebarProps>();
        var klen = RevitUnits.ConvertToDisplayUnitsLength(doc);

        foreach (var rebar in rebars)
        {

            if (IsHor(rebar, out var numesegs, out var segment))
            {
                var r = new RebarProps();
                r.diameter = GetRebarDiameter (rebar) * klen;
                r.spacing = rebar.MaxSpacing * klen;
                r.isStirrup = numesegs > 1;
                
                rlst.Add(r);
            }
        }
        return rlst.ToArray();
    }


public static double GetConfinedWidth (Element el, Document doc)
    {
        var array = GetRebarsHor (el, doc);
        foreach( var item in array)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume `item.diameter`.